# How to access Role-based Controller and view using entrust

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entrust

I'm new in `laravel`.I am using entrust Roles and permission which is working fine, but now I need to add every role like admin has his own `controller` and `view`. Superadmin should have his own controller and view.

Can anyone please help me?
How to access permission based `controller` and `view` using entrust.

This is how I tried:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
 if(Entrust::hasRole('superadmin')) {
            return View::make('superadmin');
        }
        else if(Entrust::hasRole('Admin')) {
            return View::make('admin');
        }
        else {
            Auth::logout();
            return Redirect::to('/login')
                ->with('flash_notice', 'You don\'t have access!');
        }


    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::resource('users','UserController');

    Route::get('roles',['as'=>'roles.index','uses'=>'RoleController@index','middleware' => ['permission:role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete']]);
    Route::get('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.create','uses'=>'RoleController@create','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']]);
    Route::post('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.store','uses'=>'RoleController@store','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']]);
    Route::get('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.show','uses'=>'RoleController@show']);
    Route::get('roles/{id}/edit',['as'=>'roles.edit','uses'=>'RoleController@edit','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
    Route::patch('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.update','uses'=>'RoleController@update','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
    Route::delete('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.destroy','uses'=>'RoleController@destroy','middleware' => ['permission:role-delete']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Entrust middlewares in your routes.php. add "superadmin" routes in "superadmin" middleware, "admin" routes in "admin" middleware, etc. and put the "else" case after all these.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:superadmin']], function() {
    Route::get('/someroute', function(){
        return View::make('superadmin');
    });
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('/someroute', function(){
        return View::make('admin');
    });
});

Route::get('/someroute', function(){
    Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('/login')
            ->with('flash_notice', 'You don\'t have access!');
});
```

Comment: i will check your answer , but i have a question in my mind, why we didn't use Entrust::hasRole to check user role name? Fatemeh

Comment: generally, there shouldn't be such logics via if/else in routes file. this file should have only the routing duty. but as why it didn't work?. honestly, I'm not sure, as I haven't seen this kind of logic in routes file before. but I think the reason should be that we can't use special classes like Entrust in routes file. have you noticed there is no import statement at the top? and general rules usually don't apply to this special file.

Comment: i have tried your code , but not Redirect to specific Route, ... what should i do?

Comment: i want first check current user,then redirect to his controller like SuperAdmin controller or shopAdmin controller

Comment: change the get route to `Route::get('/someroute', 'ShopController@function')` to use controllers instead of views.